# is there a way to use multiple of identical attributes like nextSibling?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm sure there's an easy answer to this but I can't frame a search question which will ferret it out.

I have multiple 'nextSibling' attributes to move through a set of unadorned td tags, and I need up to 22 in all.

Is there a way to multiply these e.g. 'nextSibling x 22' rather than put:
nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling .... 22 times?

Kind regards
Ian

Comment: Post the html snippet to be  dom-queried.

Comment: I would be amazed if this was the best way to so what you want

Comment: @SIslam here's the html snippet:      <table><tr>  <td>first</td>  <td>second</td>  <td>third</td>  <td>fourth</td>   </tr></table>    So using beautifulsoup you can navigate this to extract the data by using nextSibling.nextSibling etc until you reach the required data. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient method than just multiple repetitions. I like har07 who suggests using a for loop, but there may be a more elegant way than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Is there a way to multiply these e.g. 'nextSibling x 22' rather than put: nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling .... 22 times?"

How about using simple `for` loop :

```
pivot = initiatTdElement
for i in range(22):
    pivot = pivot.nextSibling

#at this point you've done calling `nextSibling` 22x 
#and store the result in pivot variable
```